# Oracle SELECT - alias of one column as an input to another

Tags: sql, oracle, select, alias

Folks I found similar but not exact questions on this forum - pardon me if i have not done enough searching for them. This is my question..in Oracle

```
select ( t.value*2) as inst2, (inst2 * 3) as inst3
from table t;
```

the thinking behind is if `f() =  t.value*2` is an expensive call, then we do not need to make that twice..or is there an alternative query structure i could use (I am trying to achieve this in CTAS)

thanks in advance.

Comment: i would check the explain plan.. this may only be called once by the optimizer...

Comment: Randy - explain plan is not very helpful as I found out..it is misleading..let me try along the lines of what @bluefeet suggested. thanks for the heads-up.

Comment: Cheers Sebas - that's helpful and apologies for the duplicate post. I'll take a look at the other thread as well.

Answer (score 2):

Another option:

```
with cte as (
    select t.value*2 as inst2
)
select
    cte.inst2,
    (cte.inst2*3) as inst3
from cte
```

This is actually the same as in bluefeet's reply, but I would consider it easier to understand with the `with`-syntax.

Answer (score 0):

If you want to use an alias in the second calculation, then you will want to use a subquery:

```
select inst2,
    (inst2 * 3) as inst3
from
(
    select t.value*2 as inst2
    from table t
)
```

Comment: thanks for the reply @bluefeet. I'll try to restructure along these lines.